# Laravel Show Resource searching wrong column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have created a model and controller for my spaces (properties) which has the database structure of; `space_id`, `space_address`, `space_owner`, `space_price` etc...

However when I visit ***localhost:8000/project/space/1*** I am getting this error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'spaces.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `spaces` where `spaces`.`id` = 3 limit 1)

**Function:**

```
public function show($id)
{
        $space = Space::find($id);
        return view('space.show')->with('space', $space);

}
```

This is my model if this helps:

```
class Space extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'spaces';
    public $primarykey = 'space_id';
}
```

Comment: Shoudln't $primaryKey be protected isntead of public?

Comment: @FrankProvost changed it now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should use

```
$primaryKey = 'space_id';
```

instead of :

```
$primarykey = 'space_id';
```

Notice that the [case sensitivity](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php#language.variables.basics) for the variables names in PHP:

> Variables in PHP are represented by a dollar sign followed by the name of the variable. The variable name is case-sensitive.

Comment: good finding ! Didn't notice the minor k

Answer (score 3):

In your table there is `space_id` but Eloquent query looking for `id` column. You must update column name `space_id` to `id` then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

you should correctly set your primary key in your model:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'space_id';
```